# Why I need promise in callback from $resource request

Tags: angularjs

There is request in my controller:

```
        WorkersService.all.query({}, function(data) {
            $scope.workers = data;
        });
```

I have noticed that when iterating over `$scope.workers` like
this: `for(var i in $scope.workers)...` I get all items + 2. I.e:

```
0: Resource
1: Resource
2: Resource
3: Resource
4: Resource
$promise: Promise
$resolved: true
length: 5
__proto__: Array[0]
```

1. So callback parameter is promise?
2. Why I need promise in callback if I am sure that response is already in `data`
3. I have solution to this just simply use angular.forEach but how to retrieve "clean" data from inside this callback ?

Answer (score 0):

1 So callback parameter is promise

No , you can use $promise instead of callback

```
     WorkersService.all.query().$promise.then(function(data){
        $scope.workers = data;
     });
```

2.Why I need promise in callback if I am sure that response is already in data

Now you know why then return $promise in callback response

3.I have solution to this just simply use angular.forEach but how to retrieve "clean" data from inside this callback ?

Simply use `$scope.workers = data.data` instead of `$scope.workers = data`

Comment: data.data is undefined in this case